# Adjust table and picture size in latex according to page size

Tags: pdf, latex, tabular, tex

I am trying to adjust my table and picture size in latex. I tried all ways but not table neither picture is adjusting according to my page size. My original table and picture size in pdf when I run my latex file is in this image

[image]

Here is my code for the table:

```
\linespread{1.9}

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Feature   Extraction                         & Feature selection                     & classifier & Accuracy & Precision & Recall \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{*}{GLCM/GLDM Texture Features} & \multirow{3}{*}{No Feature Selection}      & SVM-RBF    & 85    & 93     & 73  \\ \cline{3-6} 

                                             &                                       & KNN        & 86    & 91      & 78  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & Rf         & 93   & 95     & 89  \\ \cline{2-6} 


\multirow{7}{*}{}                            & \multirow{3}{*}{Trace Ratio}          & SVM-RBF    & 59    &69     & 24  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                                                                

                                             &                                       & KNN        & 64    & 62     & 58 \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & RF         & 87    & 89     & 82  \\ \cline{2-6} 




\multirow{7}{*}{}                            & \multirow{3}{*}{SVFS}          & SVM-RBF    & 65    &68     &  22 \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                                                                

                                             &                                       & KNN        & 79    & 62     & 60  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & RF         & 93    & 95    & 86  \\ \cline{2-6} 

\multirow{7}{*}{}                            & \multirow{3}{*}{PCA}          & SVM-RBF    & 61    & 64     & 42  \\ \cline{3-6}                                   

                                             &                                       & KNN        & 60    & 58     & 50  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & RF         & 58    & 55     & 52  \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multirow{7}{*}{}                            & \multirow{3}{*}{Univariate Selection}   & SVM-RBF    & 71 & 80    & 50  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                                                                 

                                             &                                       & KNN        &73    & 72    & 70  \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                             &                                       & RF         & 74    & 75    & 67  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{adjustbox}
```

And here for the figure:

```tex
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=6cm,width=.9\textwidth]{newpic1.JPG}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, I provided an edit to your question. I'm not sure whether you can see that. I think you should simplify your example and make it a minimal, reproducible example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: can you please make a compilable [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for some other solution instead of the table (`tabular`) inside the environment `adjustbox`.

For example, the package `tabularx` and the environment with the same name: here columns denoted with `X` have the width automatically calculated to fit in this case the `textwidth`. We should go a bit deeper into the use of packages [`tabularx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and [`multirow`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) together, but most of your `\multirow{7}{*}{}` in the first column were redundant so I took them all off.

The syntax for the image was correct and working as expected.

This is a sketch of code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}

\begin{document}
%\linespread{1.9}
%\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Feature Extraction         & Feature selection    & classifier & Accuracy & Precision & Recall\\\hline
GLCM/GLDM Texture Features & No Feature Selection & SVM-RBF    & 85       & 93        & 73\\\cline{3-6}
                           &                      & KNN        & 86       & 91        & 78\\\cline{3-6}
                           &                      & Rf         & 93       & 95        & 89\\\cline{2-6}
                           & Trace Ratio          & SVM-RBF    & 59       & 69        & 24\\\cline{3-6}
                           &                      & KNN        & 64       & 62        & 58\\\cline{3-6}
                           &                      & RF         & 87       & 89        & 82\\\cline{2-6}
                           & SVFS                 & SVM-RBF    & 65       & 68        & 22\\\cline{3-6}
                           &                      & KNN        & 79       & 62        & 60\\\cline{3-6}
                           &                      & RF         & 93       & 95        & 86\\\cline{2-6}
                           & PCA                  & SVM-RBF    & 61       & 64        & 42\\\cline{3-6}
                           &                      & KNN        & 60       & 58        & 50\\\cline{3-6} 
                           &                      & RF         & 58       & 55        & 52\\\cline{2-6}
                           & Univariate Selection & SVM-RBF    & 71       & 80        & 50\\\cline{3-6}
                           &                      & KNN        & 73       & 72        & 70\\\cline{3-6}
                           &                      & RF         & 74       & 75        & 67\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
%\end{adjustbox}

\begin{figure}[hp]%[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=6cm,width=.9\textwidth]{newpic1.JPG}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And its output:

[image: screenshot of output]

Answer (score -1):

**Suggestions regarding your figure:**

- I don't know the problem with your figure. It looks good to me. Did you include the package `graphicx`?
- You can further drop the `height`, if width is the limiting factor. Like so: `\includegraphics[width=0.8.\textwidth]{fig.JPG}`

**Suggestions regarding your table:**

- Drop the first column as it has the same value for all rows. Then it might already fit.
- Drop the `adjustbox. I'm not sure whether it helps here.
- Limit the width of certain columns using `p`, as e.g. in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62710/tabular-with-p-type-columns-to-fill-page-width). So in your code try `\begin{tabular}{|l|p{2cm}|l|l|l|l|}`. I don't know whether this interacts with `multirow` though.
- Drop some of the borders between the cells, e.g. `\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|ccc}`

I hope some of these suggestions will help.